# Klein-Gordon and Green's Function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

I want to prove the following relation:
$$(\partial_x^2 + m^2)\langle0|T\phi(x)\phi(x_1)|0\rangle = -i\delta^{(4)}(x - x_1).$$

My Approach: Consider LHS

$$(\partial_x^2 + m^2)\langle0|T\phi(x)\phi(x_1)|0\rangle = [(\partial_x^2 + m^2)\Theta(x^0-x_1^0)]\langle0|\phi(x)\phi(x_1)|0\rangle + [(\partial_x^2 + m^2)\Theta(x_1^0-x^0)]\langle0|\phi(x_1)\phi(x)|0\rangle$$
$$ = [\partial_x^2\Theta(x^0-x_1^0)]\langle0|\phi(x)\phi(x_1)|0\rangle + m^2\Theta(x^0-x_1^0)\langle0|\phi(x)\phi(x_1)|0\rangle + [\partial_x^2\Theta(x_1^0-x^0)]\langle0|\phi(x_1)\phi(x)|0\rangle + m^2\Theta(x_1^0-x1^0)\langle0|\phi(x_1)\phi(x)|0\rangle.$$
Now I can use the property $$\partial_x^2\Theta(x^0 - x_1^0)f(x,x_1) = -\delta(x^0 - x_1^0)f'(x,x_1) ,$$ and then use canonical commutation relation on $\phi(x_1)\  \textrm{and}\  \pi(x)$.
But what to do with $m^2$ terms?

I know the correct calculation is almost same as in Equation (2.56) of Peskin & Schroeder. But I dont understand the first line of that i.e.,
$$(\partial^2  + m^2)D_R(x-y) = (\partial^2\Theta(x^0- y^0))\langle\cdots\rangle + 2 (\partial_\mu\Theta(x^0 - y^0))(\partial^\mu\langle\cdots\rangle) + \Theta(x^0 - y^0)(\partial^2 + m^2)\langle\cdots\rangle$$
where, $\langle\cdots\rangle = \langle0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle.$

Comment: This is a lot easier to prove if you actually write out the Feynman propagator as $$\int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{i}{p^2-m^2}e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}$$ which is equal to the expression you've written if you follow the derivation. This is equation (2.59) in Peskin & Schroeder's book. A nicer (in my opinion) derivation of the Feynman propagator in this form is given starting on Page 36 of Timo Weigand's QFT lecture notes if you're able to access those. From here it's much easier to see what the mass squared term is doing because the full $p^2-m^2$ is in the denominator, it just cancels to $1$.

Comment: Thanks @Charlie for the reply. But I want to prove this the way I mentioned because I want to generalize it as Equation 5.42 in Timo Weigand's Notes.

Comment: Ok, consider replacing the $\langle 0 |\phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle$ with the propagators then. See (1.158) and (1.161) in Weigand's notes.

Comment: Please look at my question. I do not want to prove it using Feynman Propagator. because for two fields it is easy with replacing the correlator with Feynman Propagator but 3 or more fields one has to prove it explicitly.

Comment: I believe at some point you're going to have to substitute something. Whether it's the field operators for their mode expansion or whatever.